# How do we delete a batch of constraints in docplex?

Tags: python-3.x, cplex, docplex

I used a list of a constraint numbers or a list of constraint names but this does not work with command m.remove_constraints().

m.add(sumbs[i] <= a[i], "ct_sum_%d" %i)

A.append("ct_sum_%d" %i)

Then later on when I want to change the model: m.remove_constraints(A)

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Model.add_constraints()` returns the list of newly added constraints.

Similarly,  `Model.remove_constraints` takes a collection of constraint objects, not names , not indices. For example:

```
cts = mdl.add_constraints(...)
mdl.remove_constraints(cts[:3]) # remove the first three
```